# How to add labels to merged PR automatically using github Actions?

Tags: github, github-actions

Need to setup github action for a repository which automatically adds "hacktoberfest-accepted" label once the PR is merged.
Tried with just pull_request_target but the action did not got invoked so added pull_request too but still even on Merging the action is not getting invoked.
Confused about what is causing this issue or is there any other method to achieve the same thing?

Workflow code

```
on:
  pull_request_target:
    types:
      - closed
   pull_request:
    types:
      - closed

jobs:
  label:
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      # https://github.com/marketplace/actions/pr-labeler-based-on-multiple-rules
      - uses: srvaroa/labeler@v0.8
        with:
          config_path: .github/labeler_config.yml
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
```

Config file

```
version: 1
labels:
  - label: "hacktoberfest-accepted"
    size-above: 1
```

Took help from [here](https://blog.dipien.com/add-useful-labels-to-your-pull-requests-with-github-actions-33c3f8ca59b2).

P.S. : Rest of the workflow files are working as expected.

Comment: The workflow code that you included has a syntax error in line 5. The indentation before `pull_request:` is too big. This probably leads to the workflow not being executed.
I created a test repo without the syntax error and everything worked fine

Comment: Extremely thankful for your reply but even after correcting the indentation it is not getting invoked.
I have created a [test repo](https://github.com/yashjoshi-dotcom/dlt) where you can go through the closed merge requests once and see that it is not being invoked. There are other workflows that are working as expected in the opened PR.
Any other configuration change that I am missing on the repo?

Comment: Final Edit: There is nothing wrong with the code expected the indentation error pointed out in the above comment, I had missed the ..yml extension due to which it was not being invoked.
Thanks a lot, @grottenolm for helping out with indentation.